# Apple Automator “zsh:1: command not found: legendary”

Tags: macos, terminal, automator, zsh

This might be the thousandth post about this, but I can't find the answer. Anyway as the title states when I try to run a terminal command to use something called legendary in automator which is an alternative launcher for epic games that is great as it allows you to run games in Wine on Mac and Linux. Although when, I go to run the command `legendary launch bloonstd6` in the run shell script block in the Automator app it spits out this error

```
"The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: 
“zsh:1: command not found: legendary” zsh:1: command not found: legendary
```

I haven't found a way to fix this issue and if it does help this was installed using pip but running it in python3 shell it still doesn't work. All and any help is appreciated! I'm also using an apple silicon mac running macos 14 sonoma dev beta 1. The firmware that I am using should not matter but I thought I might as well chuck that out there.

Comment: Your path likely wasn’t set.  Try setting the path in the script before it calls legendary.  It will be line 1

Comment: What do I need to set the path to? I've seen people set different paths and it still doesn't work. I also tried changing the path to where the pip stuff is installed and it still won't work. I am not very good at automator.

Comment: Automator’s `Run Shell Script` action does not read any configuration files, so the $PATH environment variable will not have any of your changes - you can also use full file paths for the executables.

Comment: Open Terminal and type `which legendary`.  It will give you the path to the executable.   Use that info instead of just calling the executable by itself.

Comment: @Allan I've tried to do that before and it hasn't worked. But to make sure I'm doing it right here is the path to the executable `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/legendary`
Are you able to tell me what the code would be. I want it to run the code `legendary launch bloonstd6`

Comment: You could specify the absolute path to _legendary_  explicitly. An alternative would be to place the PATH setting into your ~/.zshenv (i.e. `path+=/Library/..../bin`). This file is processed by every new zsh, so be careful: If you make an error there, none of your new zsh instances will work properly.